# how to allow null on select inlinecreate field?

Tags: laravel-backpack

So far everything works fine except for allowing it to accept null.

```
        $this->crud->addField([
            'name'          => 'gender', 
            'label'         => 'Gender',
            'type'          => 'relationship',
            'placeholder'   => '-',
            'ajax'          => false,
            'allows_null'     => true, //doesn't work
            'inline_create' => true,
        ]);
```

Comment: That's weird. By any chance, is the foreign key column in db `nullable`?

Comment: yes, it's nullable.

Comment: i tried to edit and comment the condition in fetch_or_create.blade.php but still wont work

` $(element).append('<option value="">'+$placeholder+'</option>');`